# Can this be shortened? font = font ? font : defaultFont;

Tags: objective-c, c

Do you know a better way to write

```
font = font ? font : defaultFont;
```

all else I know is:

```
if(!font) {
    font = defaultFont
}
```

I know it's a gadget questions but who know what could come up.

Comment: `font || (font = defaultFont);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY NICE! i have a silly question, why it doesnt work without the parenthesis?

Comment: because assignment in a test must be surrounded by parenthesis

Comment: @Anton.P `||` is a higher priority operator than `=`.

Answer (score 3):

Syntactically you can shorten it using a [gcc extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Conditionals.html#Conditionals):

```
font = font ?: defaultFont;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a shortcut syntax `?:` used like this:

```
font = font ?: defaultFont;
```

which is shorthand for

```
font = font ? font : defaultFont;
```

This is from a GCC extension, and also works by default with clang, so should just work for you.

Comment: It's not so much an Objective-C thing as a gcc extension which works for C, C++ and Objective-C. It's not portable though.

Comment: While that's true, it is an extension that is in place by default in the standard environment one would be using objective-c, so I wanted to make it clear that no additional effort would be required. Will edit the answer to make it more correct.

Comment: Sure - note that the question is tagged both C and Objective-C though - it's good to keep answers as generally applicable as possible.